# YourKit Profiling and Line Numbers

Tags: java, profile, decompiling, line-numbers, yourkit

I am using the YourKit Java profiler to find CPU hogging spots in some Java code. I do not have the original source code for the Java classes, so I have been decompiling it to see what needs to be fixed.

The line numbers on decompiled code (using JD-GUI, I have not tested with anything else yet) **do not** line up with those shown in the YourKit profiler CPU sampling window.

**Is there a decompiler available that will match up original source file line numbers with the decompiled code?**

As you can see below, the output line number for EnergyNetwork.getAcceptors() is line 86. Yet, in JD-GUI it shows line 86 to be a list.

[image: YourKit output]
[image: Decompiler Output]

Answer (score 0):

I had great results for the (foreign) code I use with JD-GUI, as long as the code was not obfuscated. Did you try the latest version of JD-GUI ?
And just an idea: is the code you get so fit that it could be compiled again ? This way you might have better control about code to source mapping and in the end this would be necessary anyway because you want to fix the performance problem.

Comment: I will test that and get back to you

Comment: Deobfuscating it had no visible effect on line numbers

Comment: It looks like the code is not obfuscated. The names of methods and variables are quite  "pretty".
Just a wild guess: perhaps the Arrays.asList() together with whatever getAcceptors() does is what causes the problem ? Then the line mentioned would be correct and the profiler just shows the name of the surrounding method because he is not able to show specific code lines ?

Comment: Perhaps you should check what is in lines 167 and 149. Do they contain a method name or a statement ?

Comment: I have checked those, line 149 is an if statement and line 167 is not visible (I'm guessing because the decompiler was not able to identify which line number it was)